# Parsing fwf text to .csv for use with excel using python

Tags: python, csv

I have a fixed with text file that can run to about 50,000 lines or so:

```
 RECORD TRANSACTN       SEQUENCE    CR      R/T          ACCOUNT RSN               ITEM           ITEM CHN          USER    REASO
    NBR       NBR       OR PIC NBR  DB      NBR              NBR COD             AMOUNT         SERIAL IND  .......FIELD..  DESCR
  5,556        01        7450282689 C 538196640        9835177743 15          $9,064.81              00                    CREDIT
  5,557        01        7450282690 D 031301422         362313705 38            $592.35           43431                    DR CR
  5,558        01        7450282691 D 021309379         601298839 38          $1,491.04           44896                    DR CR
  5,559        01        7450282692 D 071108834            176885 38          $6,688.00            1454                    DR CR
  5,560        01        7450282693 D 031309123     1390001566241 38            $293.42            6878                    DR CR

 ************************************************************************************************************************************
 *                                                                                                                                  *
 *                                              PPPPPP  DDDDDD   CCCCC  K     K  #   #                                              *
 *                                              P     P D     D C     C K   K   #######                                             *
 *                                              P     P D     D C       K K      #   #                                              *
 *                                              PPPPPP  D     D C       KK       #   #                                              *
 *                                              P       D     D C       K K      #   #                                              *
 *                                              P       D     D C     C K   K   #######                                             *
 *                                              P       DDDDDD   CCCCC  K     K  #   #                                              *
 *                                                                                                                                  *
 *                                                                                                                                  *
 * START ******************************************************************************************************************** START *
 * START ******************************************************************************************************************** START *
 * START ******************************************************************************************************************** START *
```

There are random line brakes and header information between groupings of these lines throughout the file.  I am only concerned with the rows containing the letter "C" AND only if the first two numbers in the 3rd column are 74.  Each value is in it's own cell but with my different attempts at splicing, the final product looks like a mess. I've written headers in the csv module for the first row, but the actual data below them look like python threw up.

I have so far tried splicing within the csv module as well as using str.find(str, beg, end).  I feel like the solutions I have found work for the specific problem, but I cannot culminate them into a single workable code.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: The code I have thus far with the csv/codecs module is

```
import codecs
import csv


with codecs.open(r'C:\Users\John\Documents\ATM project\PDCKCR09R009_2017-08-03_1115.txt') as f, open('output.csv', 'w') as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    writer.writerow([ 'TRANSACTN_NBR', 'RECORD_NBR', 
        'SEQUENCE_OR_PIC_NBR', 'CR_DB', 'RT_NBR', 'ACCOUNT_NBR', 
        'RSN_COD', 'ITEM_AMOUNT', 'ITEM_SERIAL', 'CHN_IND', 
        'REASON_DESCR', 'SEQ2', 'ARCHIVE_DATE', 'ARCHIVE_TIME', 'ON_US_IND' ])



    for line in f:
        #f.extend(line.splitlines())
        if 'C' in line:
           #temp.append(line) 
           print(line)
        else:
            print('WRONG LINE:', (line))
```

I'm trying piece by piece to have a working segment before moving on to the next requirement but I've seem to hit another wall.  other solutions on this form have been helpful, but I am having trouble adapting it to my code

Comment: Can you post the code that you do have?

Comment: Is it a requirement to use `csv`?

Comment: it was recommended, but as long as the desired output is achieved then I dont think it matters
The formatting should be stripped of dollar signs, commas etc as well so I'm not sure if that's easier in csv or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for this, without `csv`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

with open('./data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        values = line.split()  # this splits your line using spaces as delimiter, like in your data
        if (len(values) >= 4 and values[3] == 'C'
            and len(values[2]) >= 2 and values[2][:2] == '74'):
            print(line)
        else:
            print('WRONG LINE: ' + line)
```

Output with data from the question:

```
  5,556        01        7450282689 C 538196640        9835177743 15          $9,064.81              00                    CREDIT

WRONG LINE:   5,557        01        7450282690 D 031301422         362313705 38            $592.35           43431                    DR CR

WRONG LINE:   5,558        01        7450282691 D 021309379         601298839 38          $1,491.04           44896                    DR CR

WRONG LINE:   5,559        01        7450282692 D 071108834            176885 38          $6,688.00            1454                    DR CR

WRONG LINE:   5,560        01        7450282693 D 031309123     1390001566241 38            $293.42            6878                    DR CR
```

Comment: With that code I am getting a lot of "wrong lines" but I dont actually see any lines with 'C'
It looks like it's printing everything except that

Comment: @mcclayjr01 Maybe it would have been interesting to see other lines of your data, the ones that may cause problems. I add the output I get with the data you've posted.

Comment: I've edited my original question with more of the text file.  There are multiple instances of those kind of headers throughout the text file and not just at the top.  I'm assuming I have to take the position of the data into account? When I tried to denote a starting location I still ran into the random asterisk headers throughout the file

Comment: Even with these headers, the code does what is asked: each complying line is printed "as is" (i.e. only one in your example) and all others are printed with a leading "WRONG LINE", even the headers' lines. Isn't it what you want? If you only want to print the lines you're interested in and not the wrong ones, then remove the `else` part.

Comment: I think I am missing something - removing the else and last print statement causes nothing to print - though no errors as well
leaving the else in causes all of the wrong lines to print but not the C line

Comment: never mind - after I copied and pasted the code, I fat fingered the "74" thinking it was off
I never thought I'd be on a 16hr python bender
I appreciate your time and quick responses!